# UEFI - Linux Mint Boot from USB Doesn't work

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, uefi, bootable

I'm running Linux Mint (only OS other than in VirtualBox) and wanting to remove it. I've created a Live USB of Windows 8 using Windows 7 USB/DVD Download Tool - Yes, I know it says Windows 7 but I've been doing research and I am hearing from everywhere that it also works for Windows 8.

- The ISO was loaded on just fine (AFAIK)
- Computer came with Windows 8 pre-installed
- I have Safe boot and Fast boot disabled in the BIOS Settings
- I have USB as my first boot option
- I have tried both the USB 2.0 and 3.0 ports

Yet, Mint is all that will boot up.

Anybody have a similar issue????

The computer is a Toshiba Satellite S855D Laptop with an AMD APU quad-core processor (3 CPU, 1 GPU)

Answer (score 3):

While trying different things, I've got it to work and am now operating on Windows again.

Solution:

**Legacy Boot** inside the BIOS settings should be enabled. I believe the selection will be labeled as **CSM** (as opposed to **EFI**) and in the accompanying description it is referred to as legacy.

Started right up from the USB.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest starting by making a live media [GParted](http://gparted.org/livecd.php). Boot with that, and wipe the Hard drive clean, and start installing with a completely wiped hard drive.

When you manage to boot into a Windows PE, you might wanna run `fdisk /mbr` to reinstall the bootloader.